# How can the composition inference rule be used to prove the correctness of a program split in two segments?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So the basic setup is you have a program segment S and it is split into two segments S1 and S2. You know for a fact S1 is partially correct with respect to initial assertion p and final assertion q, you also know S2 is partially correct with respect to initial assertion q and final assertion r. Now in the book I use they show at that S is partially correct with respect to intial p and final r with the inference rule

p{S1}q

q{S2}r

:. p{S1;S2}r

which is something like

( ((p ^ S1 terminates) => q)  ^  ((q ^ S2 terminates) => r ))  ) => 
 ((p ^ S terminates) => r)

I am trying to pattern match it with the generic inference rule

p => q

q => r

:. p = > r

I dont see how they can have used this rule correctly as the q condition is different for the two premises.

For the first premise I get the right hand side as only q whereas on the second premise I get the left hand side as q ^ S2 terminates, and they ought to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $$p\land S\text{ terminates}\;.$$ Then $$p\land S_1\text{ terminates}\land S_2\text{ terminates}\;,\tag{1}$$ so in particular $$p\land S_1\text{ terminates}\;.$$ Now use the hypothesis $$(p\land S_1\text{ terminates})\to q$$ to infer $q$. This shows that $$(p\land S\text{ terminates})\to q$$ and hence by $(1)$ that $$(p\land S\text{ terminates})\to(q\land S_2\text{ terminates})\;.$$ Finally, use the hypothesis that $$(q\land S_2\text{ terminates})\to r$$ to infer that $$(p\land S\text{ terminates})\to r\;.$$